# Appcelerator equivalent to Java's 'setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)'

Tags: android, titanium, scrollview, appcelerator

Trying to show the scroll indicators at all times for a scroll view.

Native Android has a method scrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false)'

Cant find how to do this in Appcelerator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At this time I don't think you can easily have the scroll bar show at all times within a scroll view, because as I'm sure you know, Titanium's `showVerticalScrollIndicator: true` hides the scroll bar with time.

The best solution is to create a custom scroll bar that works as you want.

Do this:

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
});
window.add(scrollView);

var changingTop = 0;

var scrollBar = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: changingTop,
    height: 120,
    right: 6,
    width: 6, 
    backgroundColor: '#000',
});
window.add(scrollBar);

scrollView.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    scrollBar.setTop(changingTop + e.y);
});
```

Just tested this solution and it worked for me. Reply if any questions. Cheers!